# Can I contain my em sized font inside a px line-height?

Tags: html, css

The CSS I am looking at looks like this:

```
header .logo {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 77px;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Web Light", "Segoe UI Light", "Segoe UI Web Regular", "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is likely to be a problem if I move to a mobile device? Should I ALWAYS contain a font with em size inside a line-height with em size ?

Comment: no, because the line height will always be the same and the font size may change. You may end up with 140px font size and a smaller line height.

Comment: Waiting for this answer, and its a Good Question

Comment: How can the size of the font increase?

Comment: em size is defined by browser and may be inherited

Comment: 1em is equivalent to the base font size of the users browser. So if they use 16px as standard then 4 em is 64px. IE If they increased the font size to 80 then it will be displayed as size 320px, wheras the line height will always be 77px

Comment: @Michal: No, it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `px` unit and the `em` unit are very different. The `px` unit denotes a pixel, which is a relative concept and may vary by presentation device (see [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/) for a detailed explanation), whereas the `em` unit, when used in the value of a `font-size` property, denotes the font size of the parent element. That size varies by context, by CSS rules applied, etc., and is ultimately under the control of the user. So it can be just about anything. If you assume `em` to be something specific in pixels, then the assumption will inevitably fail in some situations; and if you assume a specific size, why not use `px` throughout?

So you should set `font-size` and `line-height` using the same unit or using units with fixed, well-defined relation. Usually, you should set both in `em` units, or both in `px` units, to make sure they fit together. You can however use a pure number for `line-height`, like `line-height: 1.2`, if you set font size in `em`, since the pure number effectively has `em` as the implied unit except for inheritance issues.

For example, either

```
line-height: 77px;
font-size: 64px;
```

or

```
line-height: 1.2em;
font-size: 4em;
```

would be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

`em` unit is:

> Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used.

That's what the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#em-unit) says.

So, in your case `font-size` will be four times bigger (*4em*) than it would be normally inherited and `line-height` will be **always** *77px*.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you should generally abandon your approach because no matter how your `font-size` changes the `line-height` will be always the same. I suggest setting `line-height` in em.
**Personally**, I use `em` units very rarely. I try to always work with `px`. I do a lot of responsive design.

Comment: You mention that you work in px but I read that this can be a problem for smaller screen size. Do you designs work okay with all screen sizes ?

Comment: In `font-size`, the `em` unit has a different meaning: it refers to the font size of the parent element. And setting `font-size` prevents inheritance.

Comment: We (in the co. I work) design for devices from 200px wide. Everything is ok. But we don't design for _every_ resolution but only most popular like iPhone landscape/portrait, SGS3 l/p, tablet l/p and so on.

Comment: @Jukka that's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
In theory, the em unit is the new and upcoming standard for font sizes on the web
```

I don't think using **em** here would be a good idea, specially when your viewing device ranges from `normal computer screen to a mobile device`

[Comparing EM, PX, PT and %](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

Here your Line height is persistent to 77px but the size of em will change as per as viewing device.